# cant connect remote database while installing drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, webserver, centos7

Can anyone know what am i missing ?

**I get error**

> "*Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the
>   following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL
>   server on '192.168.0.20' (13)."* while installing drupal.

credentials are correct.

On webserver command line: `mysql -u dbuser -h 192.168.0.20 -P 3306 -D drupal -p` works fine.

what could be problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1

was solution.